# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un input con dos botones uno para sumar y otro para restar el valor de dicho input en Angular 12?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input, angular12

Estoy empezando con Angular y debo hacer un input que tenga un botón para incrementar su valor y otro para disminuirlo algo como [-]**10**[+], este es el código que tengo de html.

```
<input type="number" value="0" class="in-con-number" id="numero" min="0" max="100" #numero>
<button class="btn-menos" value="" id="deincrement">-</button>
<button class="btn-mas" value="" id="increment" (click)="getInputValue(numero.value)" >+</button>
```

El TypeScript que tengo es este, con eso obtengo el número que quiero sumar pero no he encontrado en esta página algo parecido y en internet tampoco he encontrado algún documento para cambiar el texto del input, todos muestran información para optener el texto.

```
import { Component, OnInit ,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { elementAt } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'a-finsotienda';

  constructor(){
  }

  numero: number = 0;

  public getInputValue(inputValue:string){
    this.numero = parseInt(inputValue);     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale solo para que tengas un poco de contexto, Angular maneja la [interpolación de strings](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation), básicamente las variables que declares en tu archivo .TS de forma publica, se pueden visualizar en tu HTML y se pueden manipular a través de funciones o eventos en el mismo HTML.

Si vas a tu archivo TS ya tienes la variable "numero" del tipo "number"

```
numero: number = 0;

//Por detras Angular agrega por default el modificador de acceso "public"

//Algo así "public numero: number = 0;" si lo cambias a private no tendras acceso desde el HTML.
```

Bien vámonos a tu HTML:

Cambiaremos tu input porque no lo necesitamos, para ello usaremos los *interpolation strings* que siempre van entre 2 llaves y dentro de las llaves pones el nombre de tu variable que tienes en TS, ejemplo: `{{ numero}}`

Y en los botones solo quitaremos el atributo "id" ya que de momento no lo ocupamos, y tambien quitaras el atributo "value".

Y agregaremos la funcion de incremento y decremento a los botones, en general quedaría así:

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'a-finsotienda';

  constructor(){}

  numero: number = 0; //Solo mantenemos esta variable
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<h1>{{ numero }}</h1>
<button class="btn-menos" (click)="numero=numero-1">-</button>
<button class="btn-mas"  (click)="numero=numero+1">+</button>
```

En tal caso debería de sumar y restar, pruebas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]